# Using reg.exp for detecting URL

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am currently trying to build a router in a framework i'm doing.

Therefore I need to match the URL - e.g. "/blog/2006/21" with e.g. "/blog/:year/:is"

My problem is, that my reg.exp, that I am creating is accepting if the URL contains more, than I actually add to my reg.exp. I am using the preg_match function in PHP.

```
<?php
$var = '/blog/2006/21';

if(preg_match($var, '/blog\/([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)/')){
    //do something
}
?>
```

I ONLY want it to match e.g. "/blog/2006/21/"  - and not e.g. "/blog"/2006/21/some/more"

Am I doing it the wrong way - or is preg_match not the most suitable solution for this matter?

Thanks in advance,
Dennis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `$` at the end of you pattern which means "end-of-string"

Comment: That's exactly, what I was looking for. I'm embarrassed by the fact I couldn't "figure that out" myself. Maybe it is not preferable to work on reg.exp at 02:30am..
Well, thanks! It's great - and I will accept as soon as I'm allowed.
Good evening.